# JSEclipse Alternatives in Ganymede

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.4

I've been having a lot of problems with JSEclipse in Ganymede, but I haven't had much luck finding an alternative that's compatible with Ganymede (eclipse 3.4).

All I'm really looking for is code-highlighting. Anyone have any good alternatives, or do I just need to suck it up and get on with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spket](http://spket.com/) is a really nice JS plugin for Eclipse that works with Ganymede. It provides more than just highlighting (e.g. an outline view and the ability to jump to function definitions), but is still pretty lightweight.

A more detailed discussion of the various JS plugins available for Eclipse is available here [JavaScript editor within Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678/eclipse-javascript-editor)

Comment: nice answer and nice avatar :)

Comment: Oops, I should have searched better. Thanks a lot!!