# Javascript as command line callable scripting language

Tags: javascript, scripting, command-line

I'm looking for a way to write some simple scripts in javascript, like I would in ruby.  For example, I might write a script like:

```
var str = "Hello World";
console.log(str);
```

And i want to able to call it from my command line like this:

```
js hello_world.js
```

Is there some sort of Javascript runtime, that includes a standard library that would allow me to do this style of script development?  I know there is node.js, but that is specific to a web server, right?

Comment: No, node.js is not specific to a web server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running javascript standalone engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075600/running-javascript-standalone-engine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js has emerged as the clear winner here, at least for me.

http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's JScript.NET:

http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Techniques/JScriptNET-Applications-at-the-Command-Line/1/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075600/running-javascript-standalone-engine), you might want to check out [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), an implementation of Javascript written in Java. Specifically, the page on the [JavaScript shell](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/shell.html) might be of interest.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

what about mozilla's spidermonkey ?

```
apt-cache search javascript interpreter
spidermonkey-bin - standalone JavaScript/ECMAScript (ECMA-262) interpreter
libjenkins-htmlunit-core-js-java - Jenkins branch of the HtmlUnit Core JS Interpreter
gnome-js-common - Common modules for GNOME JavaScript interpreters
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) you can easily run a javascript from command line and it naively supports DOM, CSS Selector and JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to do this in javascript? Why not use a language that is suitable for this type of command line environment such as Perl? Javascript's main purpose is to faciltate client-side browser control.

Comment: Mainly because I want to play with it in this context.  With javascript crossing the bounds of the browser, I figured it would be fun to explore building some simple stuff with Javascript the way that I use ruby.

Comment: Also, when someone asks a question like this then its because they are familiar with a language. If you say why not do it in perl... its not answering the question; its a lot of work to learn a totally new language. Also javascript is becoming used for server side stuff and app development and all kinds of stuff these days.