# Javascript Capabilities in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Where can I find information about the JavaScript capabilities of Eclipse? I have tried searching for this information on the Eclipse site, but I have yet to find any detailed info.

Comment: What do you mean, "JavaScript capabilities?" Which version/package of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr

JavaScript Development Toolkit (JSDT) is an open source plug-in for Eclipse. JSDT streamlines development, simplifies code, and increases productivity for pure JavaScript source files and JavaScript embedded in HTML.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-jsdt/

Answer (score 1):

Aptana Studio is a plug-in for Eclipse (or you can use it stand-alone) and it probably offers the best JavaScript support at the moment.

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2

Answer (score 1):

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr

Also, this question is basically the same as [JavaScript editor within Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678/eclipse-javascript-editor)

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the eclipse for PHP developer package and it has js support.

NOTE :
I use eclipse for a lot of stuff (PHP, Java, Javascript-ajax, HTML, Clojure, ..) and I have found out the very hard way that installing several versions of eclilpse is easier than install loads of sometimes conflicting plugins...

Comment: Thanks for the tip about installing additional versions of Eclipse.