# Javascript Editor with Syntax Error Checking and Debugging

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Does anyone suggest me Javascript Editor with Syntax Error Checking and Debugging ?

Is there any plugins available with Eclipse IDE?
Or Any Editor you can suggest which should be best for error checking and debugging.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I will remember that next time , thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse JavaScript editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678/eclipse-javascript-editor)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments,It will help for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Can you suggest me in brief how will it useful while error checking and debugging , How will it provide information help while writing anything in javascript? How can i use that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest (in conjunction with wong2's suggestion) trying the WTP plugin for eclipse. It's got godo tools for general web development.

Answer (score 0):

What I have tested:
- PHP eclipse just do coloring
- Netbeans detect syntax errors pretty well
- Atom has good autocompletion but do not check syntax