# Explain some javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there an ide/site that I can use to analyse code below and get an explanation of the various method calls such as .push & .hasClass by just clicking on the method name or something similar ?

For instance it is very easy to read the documentation behind java code typed in Eclipse.
Is there anything akin to this in javascript ?

```
 function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
  {
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') )
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
  }
```

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1006934/1048572

Comment: pretty useless function since jQuery is being used (`$(nodes).filter(".row_selected")`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678/eclipse-javascript-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse market place [lists](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/jquery) at least 2 plugins:

- [JDST jQuery](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery)
- [jQueryWTP](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jquerywtp/)

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/).